# Hearts Game Passing Cards

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

I'm trying to make this Hearts game so that i can select more than 3 cards.

This is the func that will compare how many cards i've chosen with 3

[image: 1]

it'll jump to this address if > 3

[image: 2]

so i replace the jump with NOP

[image: 3]

now i can select cards more than 3, but when i trying to pass the cards, there's msg showing, i can't pass the cards

so what am i missing ? I guess when we click the arrow button it'll compare the value again with 3, am i right?

Comment: Try setting a hardware breakpoint on where [rdi+38] is pointing at and see where this variable is accessed

Comment: [rdi+38] is the value of how many cards i chose

Comment: Exactly. And you assume this value will be addressed at another point in the executable. So, if the address, where this counter is located at stays permanent for lifetime of the game, you can use a memory breakpoint to find these other occurences. You can verify, that the address is semi-permanent by writing the address down, playing a round and comparing it.

Comment: So after i find the address which access the value, should i just NOP those address so i can pass the cards?